# Clicking on button generates two GET petitions

Tags: html

I'm building a website and I've got the following problem. When I click on a button, it generates two GET petitions, one with the primary key of the object I want to get as a parameter, and ANOTHER one with no parameter at all. I can't see why this can happen. Here's the piece of code of the button that generates both petitions.

```html
<div> <a class="btn btn-dark" role="button" href="cartel.html/?id={{cartel.pk}}" style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;background-color: rgb(52,58,64);">Ver más</a></div>
```

I'm using Django as the backend of the system.

Comment: There is nothing in your sample code that suggests 2 GET requests would be made. If you have this problem, the problem is not in this code snippet.

Comment: There must be an onclick that is triggering and not having an event.preventDefault() so both the onclick AND the href are called. `role="button"` gives the impression that you are suing some client framework too like bootstrap

Comment: If my above comment is correct, you might need `$(function(){
    $('a[role[button').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); .... }); })`

Comment: mplungjan, yes, I'm using bootstrap. Where should I include that function?